# Can't write to a mailslot on a pc while it's ok on some others

Tags: c++, winapi, ipc

First of all i appologize for my bad english because i'm not english :)

I wanted to use mailslots from vb.net. I'm quite noob about mailslots, not sure on how they works. Had some difficulties and ended to basic testing in simple c++ win32 code to firstly understand how it works without caring about vb managed/unmanaged stuff. I used vs 2010 in a virtual machine.

Here is the problem: i finally realized that my basic test program works fine on several computers but not on my developpement computer... I don't have any idea on what could be the cause and what i have to check.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

void main()
{
    HANDLE hservslot;
    HANDLE hclislot;

    hservslot = CreateMailslot("\\\\.\\mailslot\\testingslot", 0, 0, NULL);
    if (hservslot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("CreateMailslot error : %d", GetLastError());
        getchar();
        return;
    }

    hclislot = CreateFile("\\\\*\\mailslot\\testingslot", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES) NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, (HANDLE) NULL); 
    if (hclislot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        CloseHandle(hservslot);
        printf("CreateFile error : %d", GetLastError());
        getchar();
        return;
    }

    BOOL fResult; 
    DWORD cbWritten;
    BYTE buff[4] = {0,1,2,3};

    fResult = WriteFile(hclislot, buff , 4, &cbWritten, (LPOVERLAPPED) NULL);
    if (fResult)
    {
        printf("Slot written to successfully.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("WriteFile failed with %d.\n", GetLastError());
    }

    getchar();
    CloseHandle(hclislot);
    CloseHandle(hservslot);
}
```

On my computer i get the "WriteFile failed with 53" (which means "The network path was not found." according to msdn doc). On some other computers, including the virtual one, i get "Slot written to successfully."

Any idea on wich direction i should search the "bug" to fix it ?
Thx.

Edit: By the way, all the pc, including vm, are on windows 7 pro 64 bits.

Comment: The firewall of your developpment machine is maybe blocking the connection handeled by the socket.

Comment: Same thing with firewall deactivated. But thx for the suggestion.

Comment: how odd. out of curiosity, is your development machine on domain? just wondering (and also wondering if you see the same local-problem just using `\\.\mailslot\testingslot` on the client just as a test).

Comment: Workgroup, no domain here. And no error if i use `\\.\mailslot\testingslot` But of course the goal is to broadcast so i need the "*" :) I've tried with `\\worgroup\mailslot\testingslot` : same error.

Comment: 53 is `ERROR_BAD_NETPATH`. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365147.aspx) states: "If CreateFile specifies a domain or uses the asterisk format to specify the system's primary domain, the application cannot write more than 424 bytes at a time to the mailslot. If the application attempts to do so, the WriteFile function fails and GetLastError returns ERROR_BAD_NETPATH."  You are writing less then 424 bytes, so clearly `ERROR_BAD_NETPATH` can be caused by other factors that are not documented.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. Did you every find a solution to this?